# How can I indicate a truth table if its Valid or Invalid?

Tags: logic, proof-verification, propositional-calculus

Construct a truth table for Destructive Dilemma using the general symbolic notation for the rule of inference, T for true value, F for false value. **Indicate whether valid or invalid**.

Is this the correct way of proving it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It turns out Wikipedia has a [sample proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destructive_dilemma#Example_proof) that does *not* use a truth table. You may find it to be more informative.

Comment: Do you really want to prove this using a truth table for some reason? If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the truth values of the columns given by $(p\to q)$, $(r\to s)$,$(\neg q\lor \neg s)$, and $(\neg p \lor \neg r)$.

Your premises are: $(p\to q)$, $(r\to s)$, and $(\neg q\lor \neg s)$. Check for the rows where each of these premises are true along with the conclusion $(\neg p \lor \neg r)$. If a single row has each of the premises true, but the conclusion false, it is an invalid argument; otherwise, it is a valid argument.

---

An argument is valid if every argument of the same form has premises that are all true along with a true conclusion. An argument is invalid if there is an argument of the form whose premises are true, but the conclusion false.

Comment: is it not the same as "(P⊃Q)∙(R⊃S); ~Q V ~S/∴ ~P V ~ R"?

Comment: oh nvm u meant constructive

Comment: @NattyGuurl Sorry, I edited it now, it's the same as what you have, just different notation.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the following is what you are ultimately trying to prove (i.e., the destructive dilemma):
$$
[(P\to Q)\land(R\to S)\land(\neg Q\lor\neg S)]\implies \neg P\lor\neg R.\tag{1}
$$
I will present a truth table solution where we use the following notation to make things more manageable:
$$
\Omega : (P\to Q)\land(R\to S)\land(\neg Q\lor\neg S).
$$
Observe the following:
$$\boxed{
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
P & Q & R & S & P\to Q & R\to S & \neg Q\lor\neg S & \Omega & \neg P\lor\neg R & \color{red}{\Omega\to \neg P\lor\neg R} \\ \hline
T & T & T & T & T & T & F & F & F & \color{red}{T} \\
T & T & T & F & T & F & T & F & F & \color{red}{T} \\
T & T & F & T & T & T & F & F & T & \color{red}{T} \\
T & T & F & F & T & T & T & T & T & \color{red}{T} \\
T & F & T & T & F & T & T & F & F & \color{red}{T} \\
T & F & T & F & F & F & T & F & F & \color{red}{T} \\
T & F & F & T & F & T & T & F & T & \color{red}{T} \\
T & F & F & F & F & T & T & F & T & \color{red}{T} \\
F & T & T & T & T & T & F & F & T & \color{red}{T} \\
F & T & T & F & T & F & T & F & T & \color{red}{T} \\
F & T & F & T & T & T & F & F & T & \color{red}{T} \\
F & T & F & F & T & T & T & T & T & \color{red}{T} \\
F & F & T & T & T & T & T & T & T & \color{red}{T} \\
F & F & T & F & T & F & T & F & T & \color{red}{T} \\
F & F & F & T & T & T & T & T & T & \color{red}{T} \\
F & F & F & F & T & T & T & T & T & \color{red}{T}
\end{array}}
$$
As you can see, what we wanted to prove (what is highlighted in red) is a tautology. This proves the equivalence in $(1)$ using a truth table approach, but I would recommend using a truth table approach as only your last resort. Using deductions is much more elegant!